# Align the text or container to bottom

Tags: flutter, dart

here is the code:

```
Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: Container(
                  // margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: 10, top: 10, left: 20, right: 20),
                  child: ColorFiltered(
                    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                        Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7), BlendMode.dstIn),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      child: Text(
                        articles[index].title!,
                        //
                        //'${articles[index].category!.name}'.toUpperCase(),
                        style:
                            const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18),
                      ),
                    ),
```

I wrapped the container and text with Align did not work, still the texts on image center up position. I could not get it the reason

Comment: We need more context, the alignment effect depend on the parent. If possible try to provide a code that we can execute to witness the issue.

Comment: just remove `alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,`  in container.